# QT: Draw ax^2+bx+c using qcustomplot

Tags: c++, qt, math, graphics, qcustomplot

Currently I have this code:

```
void MainWindow::generateData(QVector<double>& x, QVector<double>& y, double A, double B, double C)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        x[i] = (i/50.0 - 1); // x goes from -1 to 1
        y[i] = x[i] * x[i];  // y = X^2;
    }
}
```

This method generates data for function y = x^2.

What I want to do is to draw plot for **y = A * x^2 + B * x + C.**

So how should I rewrite this method to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way would be to replace `y[i] = x[i] * x[i];` with

```
y[i] = A * x[i] * x[i] + B * x[i] + C;
```

A less obvious, but somewhat more performant approach is:

```
y[i] = C + x[i] * (B + x[i] * A);
```

Update:

In response to the question below, it appears the x-scaling factor isn't working.  So the whole routine should look something like:

```
void MainWindow::generateData(QVector& x, QVector& y, double A, double B, double C)
{
    int size = x.size() < y.size() ? x.size() : y.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        x[i] = (2*i/size - 1);
        y[i] = C + x[i] * (B + x[i] * A);
    }
}
```

Comment: @hofmn You need to make sure the x values are in the range [-1, 1].  The modification above should ensure that.